# Spring boot Ajax status of 405 ()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i could add the records but i couldn't edit the records using spring boot and ajax. i don't kow what i tried so far i attached below please look at the following code and give me the solution for it.
i have added controller and ajax function below

**StudentController**

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="/edit/{id}",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String showEditStudentPage(@ModelAttribute("student") Student std,@PathVariable(name = "id") int id)
{
    Student stds = service.get(id);
    service.save(stds);
    return "{\"status\":\"success\"}";

}
```

Index.html

```
   if(isNew == true)
            {

                url = '[[${@environment.getProperty('api.base.path')}]]/Student/save';
                data = $("#frmStudent").serialize();
                method = 'POST'


            }
            else
            {

                url = '[[${@environment.getProperty('api.base.path')}]]/Student/edit/' + studid ;
                data = $("#frmStudent").serialize();
                method = 'POST'
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url : url,
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : data,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#stname').val("");
                    $('#course').val("");
                    $('#fee').val("");
                    console.log(data);
                    getall();

                    if(data.status == "success")
                    {
                        alert("Record Addedd");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        alert("Record Updateedddd");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: The java code is doing nothing with the new data received, `Student std`.